# How to replace an element within a list within a list (a list of lists)?

Tags: python, list

I am having difficulty replacing an element in a list within a list.
My code is:

```
board_size = 2
number_of_squares_on_board = board_size * board_size


computers_places = []

while len(computers_places) < number_of_squares_on_board:

    placing = random.randint(0, number_of_squares_on_board-1)

    if placing not in computers_places:
        computers_places.append(placing)
        row = int(placing / board_size)
        column = int(placing % board_size)
        # print(computers_places)
        print("\nplacing: ", placing)
        print("col: ", column)
        print("row: ", row)

        column_list = board[column]
        column_list[row] = "[X]"

        print(board[column][row])
        print(board)
        print(computers_places)
```

The output is as follows:

```
placing:  1
col:  1
row:  0
[X]
[['[X]', '[ ]'], ['[X]', '[ ]']]
>>>>  [['[ ]', '[ ]'], ['[X]', '[ ]']]  <<<< This is what I expect to see
[1]

placing:  0
col:  0
row:  0
[X]
[['[X]', '[ ]'], ['[X]', '[ ]']]
>>>>  [['[X]', '[ ]'], ['[X]', '[ ]']]  <<<< This is what I expect to see
[1, 0]

placing:  3
col:  1
row:  1
[X]
[['[X]', '[X]'], ['[X]', '[X]']]
>>>>  [['[X]', '[ ]'], ['[X]', '[X]']]  <<<< This is what I expect to see
[1, 0, 3]

placing:  2
col:  0
row:  1
[X]
[['[X]', '[X]'], ['[X]', '[X]']]
>>>>  [['[X]', '[X]'], ['[X]', '[X]']]  <<<< This is what I expect to see
[1, 0, 3, 2]
```

However I have indicated what I expect to see with lines that start with '>>>>' in the above output.

**Q:** Within my code, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code is right, but maybe there is something wrong not show in the code.

You don't show us the initialization of `board`, I try use `board = [[""]*board_size] * board_size`, get the same output as you have shown. In the case, board is actually not your "list in list", it is one list, repeat for "board_size" times, so once you change one of the list, you change all of them.

I change the board initialization to `board = [[""]*board_size for i in range(board_size)]`, then I get the correct answer.

You can use this code to check if the lists in list are the same list or not:

```
import random
board_size = 2
number_of_squares_on_board = board_size * board_size

# good list:
board = [[""]*board_size for i in range(board_size)] 
# wrong list:
board = [[""]*board_size] * board_size
# check if they were the same
for _list in board:
    print(id(_list))

computers_places = []

while len(computers_places) < number_of_squares_on_board:

    placing = random.randint(0, number_of_squares_on_board-1)

    if placing not in computers_places:
        computers_places.append(placing)
        row = int(placing / board_size)
        column = int(placing % board_size)
        # print(computers_places)
        print("\nplacing: ", placing)
        print("col: ", column)
        print("row: ", row)

        column_list = board[column]
        column_list[row] = "[X]"

        print(board[column][row])
        print(board)
        print(computers_places)
```

Comment: For further reading, this kind of error is mentioned in _The Python Standard Library_, [4.6.1. Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common), note #2, about `s * n` style sequence multiplication:  "Note that items in the sequence `s` are not copied; they are referenced multiple times. This often haunts new Python programmers...".